# Are Hall subgroups of symmetric groups determined up to isomorphism by their order?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

(For example,) if $k$ is coprime to $n$ and there is a Hall subgroup of order $k$ in $S_n$, then it is clear, that it isomorphic to the Hall subgroup of order $k$ contained with $S_{n-1}$. But does this extend, up to determining all Hall subgroups of symmetric groups just by their order?

Edit: Immediately after typing this question, it became clear that this works by induction. The Hall subgroup of $S_{n-1}$ is in turn isomorphic to that of $S_{n-2}$, and so on, as long as it's coprime to each of $n,\,n-1\,\dots$. As soon as it's not coprime, there is no Hall subgroup of that order any more. So, by induction, they are all isomorphic. Does this sound correct?

Comment: I cannot follow your reasoning at all. Why is it clear that the Hall subgroup  of order $k$ is isomorphic to a Hall subgroup of $S_{n-1}$? Why do you say "there is no Hall subgroup of that order any more"? $S_2$ has a Hall subgroup of order $2$, and $2$ is not coprime to $2$. But I don't know the answer to the question in the title.

Comment: Do you happen to know any Hall-subgroup of $S_n$ for any $n$ that is neither all of $S_n$ nor a $p$-Sylow for some prime $p$? (For primes $p<q$ is there some $n$ such that an element of order $q$ normalizes a $p$-Sylow of $S_n$?)

Comment: @Derek, sorry I was unclear. By example: there is a Hall group of order 2 in S2. If I look for a Hall group of order 2 in S3 I will find one: the one contained the S2 subgroup. But if I look for one in S4, there is by definition no Hall subgroup of order 2 in there, because 2 is not the largest prime power of 2 that divides the order. I can similarly find a Hall group of order 25 in S10, and that will be isomorphic to the ones in S11, S12, S13, and S14, but again by definition S15 has no Hall subgroup of that order.

Comment: @j.p. I know only the slightly nontrivial case of smaller symmetric groups embedded in the next larger. For instance, the S6 subgroup in S7 makes the Hall subgroup of order 720.

Comment: Your argument shows that every Hall subgroup of order $k$ of $S_{n-s}$ is isomorphic to a Hall subgroup of $S_n$ so long as $k$ is coprime to $n-s+1,\dots,n$. But it doesn't rule out the possibility that $S_n$ could have other, non-isomorphic, Hall subgroups of order $k$, or that $S_{n-s}$ could have more than one isomorphism type of such subgroups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The results of the papers

P. Hall, "Theorems like Sylow's", Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) **6** (1956), 286--304,

which deals with soluble Hall subgroups, and

J.G. Thompson, "Hall subgroups of the symmetric groups", J. Combinatorial Theory **1** (1966), 271--279,

which deals with the non-solvable case, show that the only Hall subgroups of $S_n$, apart from the trivial group, $S_n$ itself, and its Sylow subgroups, are

- $S_{n-1}$ (and its conjugates) when $n$ is prime
- Hall $\{2,3\}$-subgroups of $S_7$ and $S_8$,

and that in the second case there is only one conjugacy class of Hall subgroups.

Since the Hall $\{2,3\}$-subgroups of $S_7$ and $S_8$ don't have the same order as any symmetric group, that gives a positive answer to your question.